# Is the following all right in formal English?

Tags: articles, writing

There are a few modern approaches that describe how to design a robust architecture for Android application. I am going to analyse them and develop a sample application that uses an apropriate architecture according to my analysis.

So, is the following sentence all right to be the title of my analysis?

**Analysis of modern approaches to building *(an)* android application architecture *(,)* and (an example of) prototype implementation.**

I've emphasised and put into the () the moments in that I doubt. I am pretty sure that "an" that goes before

> android application architecture

should be cut off, because in this case we are about to design an application architecture that is good for the application we develop, but might not be good for any other application. As well as I am pretty sure that "an example of" is not necessary in this case. Also I am not sure whether this title sounds good or not.

**Clarification**:

[@farnsy](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/66047/farnsy), thank you. It's a really helpful answer. I am actually going to consider and describe the existing approaches to building architecture of android application. I saw you got an active account on stackoverflow, so I'll provide more technical details. I am going to write about things like Clean Architecture, MVVM, SOLID, Dependency Injection, etc and other general recommendations that are helpful to develop a robust, testable, easy-scalable android application.

Why was I sure that there is no need in "an" article? Because I think architecture in my case is a general thing. You barely can just pick up an architecture for your app, because in more cases an android application has got few (not a few) appropriate architectures. And that's why you should build it, not just pick up.

If replace words like this

> ...modern approaches to building architecture of android application...

I still think there is no need in "an" even before *android application* as well, because as I mentioned I am going to write general recommendations for most apps. In **the analysis part** I am not going to just pick up a random app and build architecture for it, In **the analysis part** I'll try to consider general design approaches that fit most Android apps.

Though, in the second part I am going to pick up a random app and try to build appropriate architecture for it. That's why I got no doubts with "an" before example implementation.

If after this clarification, you still think that "an" is necessary, I'll put it in.

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Use either *an android application architecture* or *android application architectures* (plural).

Comment: @JasonBassford thank you. I will rather use _an android application architecture_ then, because in most cases one app uses a single architecture

Comment: @JasonBassford however, I am not sure about this. As I stated, in this case by *approaches to building (an) android application architecture* I mean the right architecture for a specific application. And this way I think that indefinite article there should not be there.

Comment: Then use ***(the / an) appropriate*** *android application architecture* or ***appropriate*** *android application* ***architectures***.

Comment: @JasonBassford What if replace words like this *Analysis of modern approaches to building architecture of android application* Do you think that articles is missed? Actually, I think it's like between definite and indefinite articles and that's why I was about to insert none of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely include the "an" here. "Prototype" is fine here, but it's a little redundant. You can put it back if you want, but a prototype is normally something that is new: the first example of something. If your provided implementations are just examples solving known problems, they are not really prototypes.

Note that this is not a complete sentence, so I'll just insert one possibility. Here's how I would write it:

> We provide an analysis of modern approaches to building an android application architecture as well as an example implementation.

Notice that some of this depends on what you are saying. If you are analyzing multiple distinguishable modern approaches, then presumably you would need to generate multiple example implementations.

> We provide an analysis of modern approaches to building an android application architecture and include corresponding example implementations.

I'm going out on a limb a little about what you are actually doing.

------------- response to your edit ------------------

In the context of computers, architecture is treated as a countable noun and requires "an."  It seems like you are thinking of a usage similar to

> I will demonstrate approaches to making ice cream.

in that case, there would be no "an" because ice cream is something that you discuss amounts of, rather than individual items of ice cream.  That's not really how people talk about "architecture" in technology.  There are several architectures that are possible to discuss. You will discuss approaches for a person who wishes to build a particular architecture.  The examples I provided are, I think, what you want.

Based on your response, you could also use the plural form

> We provide an analysis of modern approaches to building android application architectures as well as an example implementation.

Also, it sounds like you are discussing "best practices." You might want to use that somewhere. Also, this is a nit-pick, but I think the example implementation should be in a separate sentence.

> We provide an analysis of modern approaches and best practices for building android application architectures. We also provide an example implementation following these practices.

Comment: I really appriciate your answer. I replied, but the reply was too long and I edited my question to insert my reply.

Comment: thank you again. Your example with ice cream helped me a lot. Just last two things. 1) to clarify: all those things I enumerated (Clean Architecture, MVVM, Dependency Injection, etc) are only intermediate parts/pieces of the final architecture that will be the result of my analysis (final architecture is the result, not those parts). 2) question: if I replace words like this: *Analysis of approaches to building an architecture of **an** Android application*. Is the bolded "an" needed here?

Comment: In that case you would want to rephrase.  For example it's better to say Android application architecture to avoid repeated use of the word "an."