# approaches to 'architecture design' vs 'building an architecture' of a computer program

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

In case of software development, architecture of a computer program is a set of approaches and rules how to develop and maintain a computer program. The architecture is divided by a few layers and for each of them it's needed to consider an approach how to implement this layer. This way, all these layers together are the architecture I am talking about.

So, how would you say:

> I am going to learn some approaches to building a computer program
>   architecture

or

> I am going to learn some approaches to architecture design of a
>   computer program

Any difference between them? Are they both grammatically correct?

Comment: computer program is slightly "naive". One usually sees software.

Comment: "I am going to learn some approaches to building a house architecture" and "I am going to learn some approaches to architecture design of a house". Do either of these sentences make sense to you?

Comment: @JavaLatte I am sorry but I don't understand what you mean by "make sense to me" and why the sentence starts from "Do" not "Does"?

Answer (score 3):

Your first sentence is OK. Your second sentence is clunky and not quite idiomatic.

It would be more natural to say:

> I am going to learn  approaches to *architectural design* in computer programming.

When we have an often-used adjectival form of the noun, as we do here with **architectural**, it is better to use that adjective than to use the noun adjectivally as an adjunct modifier.

> architectural design

is more natural than

> architecture design

P.S. You could also say

> I am going to learn approaches to designing the architecture of a computer program.

That last version is potentially clearer than *architectural design in computer programming*, my earlier suggestion, since without further context the earlier suggestion might be understood to refer to using computers to design buildings.

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation. So it turns out both *to learn approaches to building a computer program architecture* and *to learn approaches to designing the architecture of a computer program* are correct. So this way, is there no difference between *to designing* and *to building* in this context? And another question: why did you put "the" before architecture? Why not "a" or zero article?

Comment: @Ivan To *design* something is to draw it or outline it. To *build* something is to make it real. You can build something *from* a design. An architect works with designs; a construction worker works with building materials.

Comment: @Ivan: Why "*the* architecture"?  Here, **architecture** is not being used as a subject in its own right, in which case there would be  no article.  (*Frank Lloyd Wright studied architecture in school.*) Rather, here it is just one of the attributes of a computer program.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo this way, *an android application architecture* in my sentence you mentioned as OK means the same as *the architecture of an android application* in the last sentence you provided?

Comment: @Ivan: I am not following you, sorry. There was no mention of Android in your first sentence, which I said was OK.  Are you asking if we strike "computer program" from that sentence and substitute *an Android application architecture* in its stead? If so, *an Android application architecture* and *the architecture of an Android application* can mean much the same thing but they do not necessarily have the same meaning. *an...* suggests there might be multiple ways to architect an Android application; whereas "the architecture" suggests there is one right way to do it.  It would depend on ...

Comment: ..how we understood "an Android application", that is, whether it was referring to a particular one or to Android applications generally.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo in my case it refers to Android applications generally

Comment: @Ivan: I would use the plural to speak generically of all Android applications: *I am learning  about the architecture of Android applications*.  If there is more than one architecture possible, I would switch to the singular to refer to Android applications generically: *I am learning about the various ways to architect an Android application*.

Answer (score 2):

- software architecture [is enough in your context]
- the architecture of a software program [or software program architecture]
- the architecture of a software application [or software application architecture]

**I am going to learn some approaches to building or designing or creating software architecture.**

computer program architecture does not sound right here and is somewhat redundant. Software architecture is more precise.

This article discusses this topic: [software architecture](https://www.codementor.io/learn-development/what-makes-good-software-architecture-101)

1) Computer architecture is one term:

"**In computer engineering, computer architecture is a set of rules and methods that describe the functionality, organization, and implementation of computer systems**. Some definitions of architecture define it as describing the capabilities and programming model of a computer but not a particular implementation.[1](https://www.codementor.io/learn-development/what-makes-good-software-architecture-101) In other definitions computer architecture involves instruction set architecture design, microarchitecture design, logic design, and implementation." 
[from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_architecture)

2) software architecture

"Software architecture refers to the high level structures of a software system and the discipline of creating such structures and systems."

additional question:

1)  **I'm going to build architecture for an Android application.** [that will be my new job, to do that].

versus:

2) **I'm going to build the architecture for an Android application**. [I have already built the architecture for the or an iOS application.]

2) I'm going to build **an architecture** for an Android app. [as opposed to building **a** site for hosting Android apps.]

Like: I'm going to drink coffee at home today, not in a café.

Comment: thank you. Actually, I am going to talk about building an Android application architecture. So the question is: should I put any article before "Android application architecture (software architecture)" in my case?

Comment: @Ivan This whole thing is about "an"? Right. Well, then: I'm going **to build architecture for** an Android app[lication]**".

Comment: First, I was wondering whether to use building or designing in my case. Looks like it's clear now. Then I saw how @Tᴚoɯɐuo used "the" before "architecture", while you uses no article, while I thought "a" is needed in this context. Now I'm confused about using an article. Also, it got interested for me "of" or "for" Android application.

Comment: @Ivan Your specific question about "(an) android application architecture" has already been asked (by you) and answered [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/182389/is-the-following-all-right-in-formal-english).

Comment: @Lambie thank you for the clarification with articles usage. I think, your examples helped me a lot to completely understand my article problem. In particular,  both *zero article* and *the* is not going to be a grammatical mistake in my sentence. And I will go with no article, since according to your example, it is exactly what I mean and need.